# How can default valued be added in a Query?

Tags: dataset, core-language, associations, query, default

I'm not understanding the the default values are not used to produced a length of 0 in the following example.  What is the right way to add default values during a query?

```
defaulter = <|"c" -> {}, "d" -> {}, #|> &  (* function to add defaults *)
dta = <|"a" -> <|"d" -> {1}|>, "b" -> <|"c" -> {2}, "d" -> {3, 4}|>|> (* data, missing entry *)
Query[All, defaulter, Length]@dta  (* try to add default then get length *)
(* <|"a" -> <|"c" -> {}, "d" -> 1|>, "b" -> <|"c" -> 1, "d" -> 2|>|> *)
(*                   ^ vs expected 0                                 *)
```

The problem I assume is this: “arbitrary functions are "ascending" operators” and therefore my defaulter “is applied after all subsequent operators have been applied to deeper levels” (from the docs).

Comment: maybe `Query[All, Map[Length]@*defaulter]@dta `?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is indeed that since both `defaulter` and `Length` are ascending operators, they are applied "bottom-up".  That is, `Length` is applied to the lowest level prior to `defaulter` being applied to the middle level.

We can defer the operation of `Length` so that it is processed after `defaulter` by means of a subquery:

```
dta // Query[All, defaulter /* Query[All, Length]]

(* <|"a" -> <|"c" -> 0, "d" -> 1|>, "b" -> <|"c" -> 1, "d" -> 2|>|> *)
```

Note that `Query[All, f]` is the operator equivalent of `Map[f]`:

```
Query[All, f] // Normal
(* Map[f] *)
```

So the expression with the subquery is equivalent to:

```
dta // Query[All, defaulter /* Map[Length]]
```

which is in turn equivalent to the expression in [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr)'s [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255676/how-can-default-valued-be-added-in-a-query#comment637439_255676):

```
Query[All, Map[Length] @* defaulter] @ dta
```

Ignoring the special value and error treatments performed by `Query`, all of these query variants are ultimately equivalent to:

```
dta // Map[defaulter /* Map[Length]]
```

whereas the original expression `Query[All, defaulter, Length]@dta` from the question is equivalent to:

```
dta // Map[Map[Length] /* defaulter]
```